# Maximize browser window for specific test case

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, robotframework

code:

```
Open browser to homepage
    Run Keyword If  '${browser}' != 'firefox'
    ...     Set Selenium Implicit wait    30
    Run Keyword If  '${platform}' == 'mobile'
    ...     Open with emulator
    ...     ELSE IF    '${platform}' == 'desktop'
    ...     Run keywords
    ...     Open Browser    url=${homepage}     browser=${browser}    #remote_url=${HUB_URL}
    ...     AND    Maximize Browser Window
```

How to maximize browser window for specific test case only?

Comment: It looks like you're doing it. How is what you're asking different from what you're already doing?

Comment: I want to do this for one test case only. And other test cases should not use this.

Actually, I've added one more test setup:
"Open browser to homepage with non maximized window"


But it returns:

Setup failed:
Keyword 'Selenium2Library.Open Browser' expected 1 to 6 arguments, got 0.

Comment: Have you tried simply closing the maximized window when you're done? The next time you open a browser window it won't be maximized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an argument to your keyword Open browser to homepage. If you give it a default value, you will not have to touch existing calls to the keyword.

`Open browser to homepage
    [Arguments]    ${maximize}=false
    ...
    Run Keyword If    "${maximize}".lower()=="true"    Maximize Browser Window`